# Defining a function that handles Dynamic arguments similar to Built-ins

Tags: dynamic, function-construction

Firstly please note that I'm using simply `Dynamic` behavior to illustrate my question, I'm not asking how to move a `Disk` or make a `Slider`.

When defining custom functions that allow interactive changing of variables I have almost always gotten by with just setting the attribute `HoldFirst` and giving the variable as a first argument and wrapping `Dynamic` where appropriate in the code defining the controller for example:

```
 SetAttributes[mySlider, HoldAll]
  mySlider[var_, range_] := Slider[Dynamic[var], range]
  DynamicModule[{a = 0.4},
  {mySlider[a, {0, 1}], Dynamic[a]}
 ]
```

But I feel that this is somewhat clashing compared to the interfaces of the build-in controllers and would like to have a similar interface such as those, namely changing such a definition to:

```
 mySlider2[var_Dynamic, range_] := Slider[var, range]
 DynamicModule[{a = 0.4},
 {mySlider2[Dynamic[a, Temporary], {0, 1}], Dynamic[a]}]
```

Which in a sense allows the full specification of Dynamic to be used, here showing for example the use of a `Temporary` setter.

For this simple example the change is rather painless, however the problem arises in situations where the code doesn't just pass on variables but needs to split them out in some way, for instance this manual implementation of a movable disk:

```
 myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_, {fstart_, f_, fend_}]] := 
  EventHandler[Dynamic@Disk[r, 1],{
   {"MouseDown", 1} :> fstart[MousePosition["Graphics"], r],
   {"MouseDragged", 1} :> f[MousePosition["Graphics"], r],
   {"MouseUp", 1} :> fend[MousePosition["Graphics"], r]
  }]
```

Now this matches the longest definition, but I would rather like not to have to provide multiple definitions for `myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_, { f_, fend_}]]`,`myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_, f_]]` and such. So my way of doing this was to set `HoldAll` and just provide rewriting calls to other definitions:

```
 myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_]] := myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r, {None, Automatic, None}]]
 myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_, {f_}]] := myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r, {None, f, None}]]
 myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_, f_]] := myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r, {None, f, None}]]
 myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_, {f_, fend_}]] := myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r, {None, f, fend}]]
 myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r_, Temporary]] := myMovableDisk[Dynamic[r, {None, Temporary, Automatic}]]
```

To me this seems like a less elegant solution to allow normal dynamic interactivity, and I have yet to actually define how for instance a Temporary setter should work. I was wondering if there was an easier way to carry out such definitions, something akin to just accepting a `_Dynamic` argument and then query it to get the values of `fstar`,`f` and `fend` in the code actually defining `myMovableDisk`?

Additionally I wonder if there is a write up of something like an interface definition for `Dynamic`, in essence answering what a function accepting `Dynamic[var]` should live up to of expectations in order to mirror a build-in function, since I'm really just working against the help page.

Comment: If you **have** to handle `f`, `fend`, `Temporary`, etc. in any way inside your function then I see no other way than writing different signatures for all cases, or combine them in one signature with `Default` and `Optional`. Or I did not understand the question.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I don't think you misunderstood the question, yet I am hoping for a more elegant way. In essence I suppose i would have liked a function akin to `AbsoluteCurrentArgument[dynvar,fstart]`, since I could very easily have implemented my wanted flexibility if `fstart`,`fend` and f where Options. As for the special treatment needed for `Temporary` that will of cause always be needed, however I think it's doable with a general pattern.

Comment: What's the need for `HoldAll`? (furthermore, you forgot "myMovableDisk` in your `SetAttributes`

Comment: Just edited the `SetAttributes`

Comment: @Rojo In the first case it's needed, I didn't remove it in the latter cases since I didn't notice that it was no longer needed since Dynamic does the holding.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is relevant, but be aware that all of these also produce manipulable sliders: `{Slider[], Slider[1], x = 1; Slider[x]}` (i.e. withouth any `Dynamic` wrapper for the input argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood, but the function you seem to want is quite similar to the function you already created for the purposes of this question, right?

For example

```
getDynamic[r_Dynamic] := getDynamic[r, All];
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_], s_] := 
 getDynamic[Dynamic[r, {None, Automatic, None}], s]
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, {f_}], s_] := 
 getDynamic[Dynamic[r, {None, f, None}], s]
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, f_], s_] := 
 getDynamic[Dynamic[r, {None, f, None}], s]
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, {f_, fend_}], s_] := 
 getDynamic[Dynamic[r, {None, f, fend}], s]
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, Temporary], s_] := 
  getDynamic[Dynamic[r, {None, Temporary, Automatic}], s];
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, {fstart_, f_, fend_}], "fstart"] := fstart;
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, {fstart_, f_, fend_}], "f"] := f;
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, {fstart_, f_, fend_}], "fend"] := fend;
getDynamic[Dynamic[r_, {fstart_, f_, fend_}], All] := {fstart, f, 
   fend};
```

You put that in some package, and from now on you can do

```
myMovableDisk[r : Dynamic[v_, ___]] := EventHandler[Graphics[
   Dynamic@Disk[v, 1], 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {{"MouseDown", 1} :> 
    getDynamic[r, "fstart"][MousePosition["Graphics"], 
     r], {"MouseDragged", 1} :> 
    getDynamic[r, "f"][MousePosition["Graphics"], r], {"MouseUp", 
     1} :> getDynamic[r, "fend"][MousePosition["Graphics"], r]}]
```

Perpahs you could summarize those `getDynamic` definitions by using defaults but the main point is that you don't need to do this coding more than once.